# JavaScript - reload image. Mapbox GL JS Static Map doesn't load, error 404

Tags: javascript, html, image

I'm  using Mapbox GL JS to create static maps.

The src of the image is the API request. Sometimes the image doesn't load and it returns the error 404 (Not Found) in the console.

I want to add a listener (or something) that checks to see if the image returns 404 (Not Found), and if it does, refresh the image to see if it loads.

When I refresh the image manually, I usually change 1 digit in one of the coordinate points (for example, 122.337798 becomes -122.337797) and then the image loads, so I don't think it's a problem with the API, I think the image is just improperly loading sometimes and returning the 404 error.

```
<img id='staticMap' alt='static Mapbox map of the San Francisco bay area' src='https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/mapbox/streets-v11/static/-122.337798,37.810550,9.67,0.00,0.00/1000x600@2x?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoibWNhcmxzb24zMzMiLCJhIjoiY2pxeWMzajA0MDIwMTQ4cGFiemU4eTd5eSJ9.fnYYeOh6-99LgMER26dIeA' >

<script>
    // Add event listener to $('#staticMap')
    // If image is 404, refresh image
</script>
```

Comment: I have the same problem. It's almost random for me. Two or three locations out of twenty won't load, and ten minutes later those ones load but a couple of others dont't. Have you found a solution to this?

Comment: Are you using a marker with a custom image path? I found that without the marker everything works fine.